# Show more than two images in Image View with delay between them in an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have just started learning android. I want to show more than two images in Image View and have have delay between them. I can do it when just two images have to show, like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) { 
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
}
```

I repeat the count down timer , but the second image not shown and the 3rd is showed. here is my question: is there any way to fix above lines or i have to do something else? thanks for replying.

Comment: Where is the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);
                    }
                }.start();
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                         Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
            if(order%2==0){
                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon1);
                        }else{
                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);
                        }
                                }
                            });

                        order++;
                    }
                },0,4000);
            }
        });

    }

    private int order = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) for this. E.g.

```
Drawable drawables[] = new Drawable[2];
drawables[0] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon1);
drawables[1] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon2);
TransitionDrawable crossfader = new TransitionDrawable(drawables);
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
img.setImageDrawable(crossfader);
crossfader.startTransition(3000);
```

the code will crossfade icon1 and icon2 in three seconds

Edit:

for n different drawables you could use a Handler. E.g

```
int drawables [] = { R.drawable.icon1, R.drawable.icon1, ... R.drawable.icon };
```

declare `int currentIndex = 0;` as member class. Then in onCreate, after

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
```

you do

```
img.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            img.setImageResource(drawables[currentIndex++%drawables.length]);
            img.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

this way the drawable will change every second without crossfading it. Call `img.removeCallbacks(null)` in `onPause`

Comment: Sorry, it works for just 2 images,though the first image doesn't disappear fine. but my problem is : i have 3 or more images.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to change the image resource parameter.
Your code always reference to R.id.icon2 and not to another image

`img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);` //your problem

You can save the images in `Drawble` array

Comment: its works fine, but for the 3rd image, and delay before it I have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right direction. Use Handler.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//Some code
},3000);
```

Comment: its work when i have just 2 images, but when i want to show 3 or 4 and write your suggested block twice or more , it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

use array

```
 int[] images = {

        R.drawable.troj1,R.drawable.troj2,R.drawable.troj3,R.drawable.troj4,R.drawable.troj5, //0-4
        R.drawable.koc1,R.drawable.koc5,R.drawable.koc3,R.drawable.koc4,R.drawable.koc2,//5-9
        R.drawable.kruh1,R.drawable.kruh2,R.drawable.kruh3, ///10-12
        R.drawable.tutorial1,
        R.drawable.tutorial2,
        R.drawable.tutorial3,
        R.drawable.nic,
};
```

call array

ImageView potom;

current_image_index = (int) (Math.random()*12); potom.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);

Comment: there is no problem with setting images, my problem is that i want to delay between set images when i have 3, 4 or more images.